# How to Integrate of strem-chat in my project?

Tags: getstream-io

I want to integrate Stream-Chat chat SDK in my MERN stack project, help needed in how to do so?

Answer (score 2):

There are libraries that can help you achieve this.

As you use MERN, refer to this:

```
https://getstream.io/chat/docs/?language=js
```

It is pretty straightforward.